# How to compare System.Timer with a TimePicker in xml UWP?

Tags: xml, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create an alarm clock in UWP xml. So I'm using system timer and try to compare it to a TimePicker that I set. But I cannot get the value of the Timepicker. There is a red underline that says "Cannot implicitly convert System.Timespan to System.DateTime".

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime userTime = timePicker.SelectedTime.Value; //here is where the error shows
        if (currentTime.Hour == userTime.Hour && currentTime.Minute == userTime.Minute && currentTime.Second == userTime.Second)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            try
            {

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Cannot implicitly convert System.Timespan to System.DateTime".

This exception is because the type of timePicker.SelectedTime.Value is Timespan, you can't directly convert it to DateTime.

If you want to compare the two data, you can convert Timespan to DateTimeOffset or convert the hour, minute, and second of the current dateTime to seconds, and compare it with timespan.

In addition, you need to get the value of timePicker.SelectedTime.Value in UI thread, you could try the following code.

```
private async void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        TimeSpan userTime = timePicker.SelectedTime.Value;
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        //Method one
        if (userTime.TotalSeconds == currentTime.Hour * 3600 + currentTime.Minute * 60 + currentTime.Second)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }

        //Or
        //DateTimeOffset combinedValue2 = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(currentTime.Year, currentTime.Month, currentTime.Day) + this.timePicker.Time);
        //if (currentTime.Hour == combinedValue2.Hour && currentTime.Minute == combinedValue2.Minute && currentTime.Second == combinedValue2.Second)
        //{
              //timer.Stop();
        //}

    });
 }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I'm currently trying your code out and would like to know abit more. What is the await Dispatcher.RunAsync for? Why did you add a * 3600 to the hour and *60 to the minute?

Comment: Also, instead of time.Stop(), I would wish to play an alarm sound. how would I go about doing that? Edit: Terribly sorry for the inconvenience, I am extremely inexperienced at this

Comment: [Dispatcher.RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync) is used to return the UI thread from a worker thread. Because I want to convert the hour, minute, and second of the current dateTime to total seconds. And then use its total seconds to compare with the total seconds of timePicker. One hour equals 3600 seconds, so *3600 to the hour and one minute equals 60 seconds, so *60 to the minute.

Comment: In addition, if you want to play an alarm sound, you can use [MediaPlayerElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement#set-the-media-source), create it in code-behind, set its source and then play it.